# Keyboard.IsKeyDown false over UAC process with uiAccess=true?

Tags: c#, wpf, uac

I have a program which tries to install itself on the target machine with `uiAccess=true` in the manifest.

Here is the documentation on that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671610(v=vs.85).aspx

According to the documentation, this should grant the application permission to do more things while a UAC elevated application is in focus.

However, as soon as an administrative application is in focus, `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` returns `false` for any key that is in fact down.

This leads me to believe that the `uiAccess` thing is not actually working.

Here's what I made sure is happening:

- My program is signed with a code signing certificate as per the documentation, from Comodo. It is not an EV certificate.
- The program is launched from a UAC protected path (`C:\Program Files\Shapeshifter`).

**How can I debug `uiAccess` and figure out why it is not working?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I debug uiAccess

The only real thing debuggable about it is to verify that the OS detected that you asked for it.  Very easy to do and something you probably already did: don't sign the executable.  With the expectation that you now can no longer start the EXE.  If it does start then you know for a fact that UIPI was not disabled.

> Keyboard.IsKeyDown returns false

That is the expected behavior and something that disabling UIPI does not fix.  This WPF property uses GetKeyState() under the hood.  Quite a notorious function at SO with many victims and very few usable answers.  Keyboard state and input handling is per-process (technically per input queue), only the process that has a window in the foreground can expect to see keypresses.  Fixing that requires using the winapi function that Raymond Chen loves to hate on, AttachThreadInput().  With the expectation that with UIPI disabled it no longer fails with error 5 (aka access denied).

Very hard to use correctly, beyond Raymond's concerns, since you need to track which window is in the foreground.  I can't tell why you need it, but surely you'd favor SetWindowsHookEx() or RegisterHotKey(), perhaps UI Automation as supported by the System.Windows.Automation namespace.

Comment: But on the following resource it says that GetKeyState is allowed for uiaccess applications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-only-elevate-uiaccess-applications-that-are-installed-in-secure-locations

Comment: Sure, after calling AttachThreadInput.  Also mentioned.  Did you try it?  Then you have code you can copy/paste into your question that others can try to repro the problem.

Comment: I tried attaching the UI thread of the main window of the UAC elevated process to my thread, and I still can't detect the keyboard state. Do I need to first push my own window to the foreground?